# laravel Unique Validation on row where is_active is 1

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8

I want to implement unique validation on one column but it should only check active rows of the table.
so is there any way I can implement this logic using laravel validation?

Below is the logic I am using to check unique records but its not working.

```
unique:users,email,is_active,1
```

Comment: I think you can put the validation in an if statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [laravel validation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-unique) document, you can do it as:

```
Rule::unique('users', 'email')->ignore(0, "is_active"),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can scope the query with additional clauses like that:

```
Rule::unique('users', 'email')->where(fn ($query) => $query->where('is_active', 1));
```

Another syntax is:

```
unique:users,email,NULL,id,is_active,1
```